# Crawl the Candy Crush saga in AppStore using Python

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

Not able to get the App name from the html , it is giving an empty list.

The code used is,

```
from urllib import request
from lxml import html
import requests

class AppCrawler:
    def __init__(self,starting_url,depth):
        self.starting_url=starting_url
        self.depth=depth
        self.apps=[]

    def crawl(self):
        self.get_app_from_link(self.starting_url)
        return 

    def get_app_from_link(self,link):
        startpage=requests.get(link)
        tree=html.fromstring(startpage.text)
        name= tree.xpath('//h1[@class="product-header__title app-header__title"]/text()')[0]
        print(name)



class App:
    def __init__(self,name,developer,price,links):
        self.name=name
        self.developer=developer
        self.price=price
        self.links=links

    def __str__(self):
        return("Name: "+ self.name.encode('UTF-8')+ "\n\r Developer: "+ self.developer.encode('UTF-8')+
        "\n\r Price: "+ self.price .encode('UTF-8'))


crawler=AppCrawler("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731",0)
crawler.crawl()
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error,

 line 18, in get_app_from_link
    name= tree.xpath('//h1[@class="product-header__title app-header__title"]/text()')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: are you sure the url you are using is the same as the one in your example?  It prints `Candy Crush Saga` with some whitespace padding every time for me.

Comment: yes, its the same url. Candy Crush Saga App in the Apple App store.
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731

Comment: Yah I don't know what to tell you... I literally copy and paste your code as is, and it works fine for me.

Comment: You can try it out here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wX6SUgxveMz8Rhjo2SMwb1MM4xA-801r#scrollTo=598zU5CkGM9l

Comment: Thanks Alexander, It works fine on colab. 
Not sure why it doesnt on VSCode. I'm getting empty list when not adding the index and index out of bound when selecting index at 0.